# How to deploy latest nuget package (AzureDevOps Artifacts) from yml pipeline on a scheduled trigger

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We have a build.yml which builds on a push to master and publishes the artifacts to a nuget feed on AzureDevops Artifacts. (not pipeline artifacts)

[image]

I also have a working deployApp.yml pipeline where the nuget package version is a parameter input and it deploys the app.

We want a scheduledDeploy.yml pipeline which gets triggered on a schedule and it should take the latest release(nuget package) and deploy it into an Azure app service container.

Should i write some custom tasks inside the scheduledDeploy.yml to fetch the list of packages and deploy it or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What do your pipelines look like?

Comment: @DanielMann, I have a .yml file like this
schedules:
- cron: "0 4 * * *"
  displayName: Daily midnight build
  branches:
    include:
    - master

so the question is should i write custom code to get the list of packages and find the latest and deploy, or , is there a better way to do this.

Comment: i have updated the original question to improve the readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a direct solution on getting the latest package version, but you can use rest api as a workaround. The script sample shared as below:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   $url = " https://feeds.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/packaging/Feeds/{feedId}/Packages/{packageId}/versions?api-version=6.0-preview.1"
   $token = "$(system.accesstoken)"
   $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
   
   $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get 
   
   $result = $response.value | Where {$_.isLatest -eq "true"} #|
   
   $latestversion = $result.version
   
   echo $latestversion
   
     echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=latestversion]$latestversion"
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'

- task: DownloadPackage@1
  displayName: 'Download Package {packageId}'
  inputs:
    feed: '/{feedId}'
    definition: '{packageId}'
    version: '$(latestversion)'
```

Here is the doc about: [Artifact Details - Get Package Versions - REST API (Azure DevOps Artifacts) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/artifacts/artifact-details/get-package-versions?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for sharing. I ended up something very similar. will post my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing very similar to what @RoyWang-MSFT suggested. using nuget instead of the REST endpoint.

```
#filename scheduledDeploy.yml
parameters:
  - name: vmImage
    type: string
    default: "ubuntu-latest"
    values: 
      - "ubuntu-latest"
  - name: serviceConnection
    type: string
    default: 'Service Principal DEV'
    values:
      - 'Service Principal DEV'
  - name: variableGroupName
    type: string
    default: 'AppDev'
    values:
      - 'AppDev'

trigger: none

schedules:
- cron: "0 4 * * *"
  displayName: Daily build
  branches:
    include:
    - master

variables:
  - name: System.Debug
    value: true
  - group: ${{ parameters.variableGroupName }}

stages:
  - stage: "MatchVersions"
    jobs:
      - job: MatchDeployedVersion
        continueOnError: false
        displayName:  "Check if latest nuget package version is to be deployed"
        pool:
          vmImage: ${{ parameters.vmImage }}
        steps:
          - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
            inputs:
              versionSpec: "6.3.0"
            displayName: "Install nuget@6.3.0"
                      
          - task: NuGetAuthenticate@1
            displayName: 'NuGet NuGetAuthenticateV1'

          - task: AzureCLI@2
            name: MatchVersionTask
            displayName: Match available and deployed versions
            inputs:
              failOnStandardError: false
              azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
              scriptType: pscore
              addSpnToEnvironment: true
              scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
              inlineScript: |                  
                  $packages = (nuget list $(packageId) -AllVersions -NonInteractive -Source "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/MyCompany/MyProject/_packaging/MyFeedName/nuget/v3/index.json" | Select-String -Pattern $(packageId))
                  $versions = @()
                  foreach ($package in $packages) {
                      $version=$package -replace("$(packageId) ", "")
                      $versions = $versions + $version
                  }                  
                  $latestVersion = ($versions | Sort-Object -descending)[0]
                  Write-Host 'latest version='$latestVersion

                  $deployedPackagConfig = (az webapp config appsettings list --resource-group $(appServiceResourceGroupNameName) --name $(appServiceName)) | convertfrom-json | Where-Object -FilterScript { $_.name -eq "PACKAGE_VERSION" }
                  $deployedVersion = $deployedPackagConfig.value
                  Write-Host 'deployedVersion='$deployedVersion

                  if($deployedVersion -ne $latestVersion)
                  {
                      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=continueDeployment;isOutput=true]true"
                      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=packageVersion;isOutput=true]$latestVersion"
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=continueDeployment;isOutput=true]false"
                  }

  - stage: "Deploy"
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.MatchVersions.outputs['MatchDeployedVersion.MatchVersionTask.continueDeployment'], 'true'))
    dependsOn: "MatchVersions"
    variables:
      packageVersion : $[stageDependencies.MatchVersions.MatchDeployedVersion.outputs['MatchVersionTask.packageVersion']] 
    jobs:
    - template: templates/deploy-app-template.yml
      parameters:
        packageVersion: $(packageVersion) 
        variableGroupName: ${{ parameters.variableGroupName }}
        serviceConnection: ${{ parameters.serviceConnection }}
```